# Primefaces's p:rowExpansion not working inside p:outputPanel?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm currently working with primeface's p:rowExpansion and noticed that it's not working inside a p:outputPanel. Here's a sample code:

```
<p:commandButton action="#{xxxSearchBean.search()}" value="Search" update="messages resultPanel" styleClass="button"></p:commandButton>

<p:outputPanel id="resultPanel">
    <p:panel rendered="#{xxxSearchBean.hasResults()}">
        <ui:include src="xxxSearchView.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="searchBean" value="#{xxxSearchBean}" />
        </ui:include>
    </p:panel>
</p:outputPanel>
```

The included view:

```
<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="0">
    <p:tab title="Criminal Results">
        <p:dataTable var="c" value="#{searchBean.results}">
            <p:column style="width:16px">
                <p:rowToggler />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Last Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{c.lastname}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="First Name">
                <h:outputText value="#{c.firstname}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:rowExpansion>
                <p:panelGrid columns="4"
                    columnClasses="form-field-label,value,form-field-label,value">
                    <h:outputText value="Label" />
                    <h:outputText value="Value" />
                </p:panelGrid>
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

The above code successfully show the result grid when there are results, but when I click the rowExpansion it doesn't work.

When I moved out the panel and remove the rendered property, the row expansion worked. But I don't want to show the grid on page load :-(

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solved the problem by changing the backing bean annotation from @Model to @Conversation scope, then start the conversation the moment the view is render.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `<p:rowExpansion>` really doesn't work with `<p:outputPanel>`. But since you don't need any special features of `<p:outputPanel>`, you can just use `<h:panelGroup>` instead. :)